# Connect IBM Speech to Text service to IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm using IBM Speech to Text service (STT) and I want to connect it to IBM Watson Assistant (WA) Plus Plan to allow ask questions in speech instead of text only.

What I want to have is a microphone icon in the chat window, in which after clicking this microphone icon a user can talk and and ask a question.

I tried to the documentation on how to connect STT to WA, however the only thing I found is how to connect STT to WA through a voice telephone line.
Any help, please?
Thanks

Comment: @data_henrik, Can you please help?

Comment: Found the link for using a voice telephone, which the OP didn't bother to link: [Integrate voice services into your Watson Assistant](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/integrate-voice-services-to-your-watson-assistant/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. However, This is not what I want.. What I want is to have a microphone icon in the chat window..

Comment: You may have to record the question and then have your website call Watson in the background.

Answer (score 1):

With the Watson Assistant web chat, you can connect it to both TTS and STT services.

For TTS, the short explanation is to use the `receive` event that is fired whenever web chat receives a message. You can send the message to your TTS service to speak the desired text.

For STT, you'll need to add a button of some sort to the UI. You are a little limited here - you won't be able to put a microphone icon inside the input field, but you can put one directly above the input field using one of the `writeableElements` (`beforeInputElement` being the most appropriate). Once the button is clicked, you'll make a call to your STT service. When it returns the appropriate text, you can use the `send` method to send the text to WA.

We even have a complete tutorial showing you how to get all the pieces working together: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-toolkit/tree/master/integrations/webchat/examples/speech-and-text

And links to the relevant documentation:

- https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#writeableelements
- https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-events#receive
- https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#send